# Unclosed connection in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

Problem: Oracle database is having unclosed connections. We need DBA setting to kill the connecions ,not sessions , many connections are from same user , but have to kill only the connections which are not used , idle connections which are not running any sql query against the database. Is there any setting in Oracle DBA  to do this ? If particular connection is not used for some time for running query(say 20 min), then it should be automatically killed or released that connection. Please help. Thanks, krishna, ekrishna10@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Oracle Database Resource Manager to do that. Of course, your dba should set this up for you to work. See [Idle Time Limit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/dbrm.htm#ADMIN11859) in the docu. Make sure that there is a dedicated resource consumer group for this kind of sessions.